# Reading all the contents in a file

Tags: excel, jsp

I've an excel document in my D drive named New. I want o see the contents of that file in my jsp. The code i'm trying is as below.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:excel");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         String myDB = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:/New.xls;" + "DriverID=22;READONLY=false";
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDB, "", "");
           Statement st=conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select  * from [Sheet1$]");
            out.println(rs);
            while(rs.next()){%>
<td><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
<%
}
            }
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e);
}
        %>
```

here basically i want to retrieve and display the first column contents in my jsp, but i'm not getting any exception or any message, the output i'm getting is just getting a blank page, just to test I've changed the file name from New.xls to New, even then there is no exception thrown, please let me know where i'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid using scriptlets in JSP.

Comment: ok sure @Aniket, but can you please let me know what is the flaw in my code?